# Add extra buttons to DataGridView scrollbar?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to find a way to add an extra button to the top and bottom of the DataGridScroll bar that will allow the user to jump to the top or bottom of the grid when clicked.

Does anyone know how to do this in a custom DataGridControl? Is there a way to add extra buttons to the scrollbar or can I shorten the height of the scrollbar somehow so I can manually add a button in at the top and bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You can put two buttons on top and bottom of datagridview (dgvLDR) 
and use the following code in button click events
This will scroll the DGV on top and bottom: -

```
btnTop_click()
    dgvLDR.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0

btnBottom_click()
If dgvLDR.RowCount > 0 Then
    dgvLDR.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvLDR.RowCount - 1
End If
```